# Estimating models in the presence of variables with different 4th moments

Tags: regression, kurtosis

I am trying to estimate a linear model where some of my features have very different 4th moments after standardizing mean 0 and variance 1.

My hypothesis is that these variables mean different things and I would like try play around with feature selection algorithms which use this information.

Are there any estimators which take the fourth moment into account or any literature I can review to better understand the implications of this of my models?

Comment: There are estimators available for kurtosis but in most instances I can't see how this would be an issue.  Why are you concerned about it in the first place?

Comment: I want to try something different with my data. Some of my features can have very different properties. I want to see what will happen if I somehow *prefer* features with lower kurtosis over features with higher kurtosis given $x_i \cdot 1$, $x_i \cdot y$, and $x_i \cdot x_i$ are the same.